# how to scroll a saved document horizontally in iphone webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiweb

i have a webviewcontroller in which i am loading a saved html page or a pdf or any other document by this code.

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yahoo" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:YES]]];
```

i an trying to load a document and show it using horizontal scroll not vertical scroll.

can someone help me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your page -

```
<link media="only screen and (max-width: 1000px)"
  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iphone.css"/>
```

You can increase the page width to suite your needs

Comment: thanks saurabh for your reply but if i have to load a pdf by programmatically showing page by page how would i scroll through them horizontally.

Comment: Please edit your question for this...right now your question is not describing your problem exactly!

Answer (score 0):

first you create the view horizontally and then you load that document to this view..then you can able to scroll horizontally....

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];  
scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;  
NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;  
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {  
CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;  
UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0,   self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];  
awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];  
[scroll addSubview:awesomeView];  
[awesomeView release];
}
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews,   self.view.frame.size.height);  
[self.view addSubview:scroll];  

[for more details][1]


  [1]: http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, as it worked fine for me:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:someIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES]
```